Is there only one way to create RBT on a paper with a given sequence of numbers?
Let's say I have sequence of random numbers that vary <1, 30>, e.g. 20, 23, 27, 15, 14, 13, 2.
Is there only one way to develop a Red-Black Tree on a paper? (i.e during exam). I mean I choose different rotation than some developed algorithm would give me?
Some case I had few days ago:
before insertion of 2 (complete 8-node RB tree)
And I wanted to add '2'.

So another question is:
Are these two trees after adding '2' acceptable?
I tried every source :c

@trincot What do you mean? Click on the "SECOND" there are two potential trees that would work. I mean the first one is 100% correct. I don't know about the second one.

Oh right, I missed that. Yes, will delete my comment.

I am still confused, because you start by saying that 20, 23, 27, 15, 14, 13, 2 are inserted, but that is not the tree in the image? For instance the image has values 10 and 16... Was that an unrelated example?

If I ignore that, and only look at the images, how did you get the second tree with 2 that you drew? Which logic, coloring and rotations did you apply? If you would program this, what would be the preconditions to apply this? Can you explain step by step?

Any clarification?

Have you lost interest in your question?

We can look at the following subtree, right after 2 is added as a leaf, without having applied any recoloring or rotation -- I mark red nodes with parentheses:
        (14)
        /  \ 
      12    15
     /
  (10)
  /
(2)

First note that a new leaf is always colored red, because that way we maintain the "black property".
The violation that is introduced concerns two red nodes that are directly connected (10 and 2). This needs to be resolved.
The algorithm described at Wikipedia - Red black tree will perform a rotation of nodes 10 and 12, after which a recoloring is applied: this is "insert case I6" in their procedure.
You have applied a different algorithm, where you apparently resolve the red-red conflict by recoloring nodes 10 and 12, so that now the red-red conflict occurs at nodes 14 and 12:
        (14)
        /  \ 
     (12)   15
     /
   10
  /
(2)

Then you perform a rotation of nodes 12 and 14, recoloring nodes 14 and 15:
     (12)
     /  \
   10    14
  /        \
(2)        (15)

This is a valid red-black tree, but:

It requires more nodes to be recolored (4 instead of 2), and

If you provide this as an answer to an exam question, you risk that you'll get a bad mark as it is clear you have not applied the standard algorithm. To count as a valid answer, the exam reviewer would have to know which alternative algorithm you have applied and what would be the general precondition to apply that specific part of the algorithm to this case. You'd then better extend your exam answer with a full specification of which algorithm you would apply to every possible configuration you could encounter, or at least provide a reference to a reputable source for that algorithm, so that the exam reviewer can verify its correctness (if they are open to students using alternative algorithms).


